# Show DevExpress DXTabControl tabs at the bottom in XAML

Tags: xaml, devexpress-wpf

Does anyone know how to use the DevExpress DXTabControl in XAML and set it up so that the tabs appear at the bottom? Here is what I have so far but the tabs show up at the top. The DevExpress documentation does not have an example of this. Intellisense does not give me anything intuitive.

```
<dx:DXTabControl>
    <dx:DXTabItem Header="Main">
        <dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
            <dxdo:LayoutGroup>
                <dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="TaskList">
                    <views:DxTaskList x:Name="Tasklst" />
                </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
                <dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="TaskDetails">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Focusable="False">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <views:TaskDetails x:Name="TaskDtls"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
            </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
        </dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
    </dx:DXTabItem>
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

Comment: I looked at https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7975 but I cannot find the property

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm not a XAML expert and it's not so obvious to me. It says the location is specified by the TabControlViewBase.HeaderLocation property but how is that translated into XAML?

Comment: They're being cheap on html, not listing all inherited properties and methods on the page for the class. Keep that in mind when reading docs for other devexpress controls.  At least MSDN doesn't do that--they even include extension methods in the docs.  As you see, Type.Property = > `<Type Property="value" />` or `<Type.Property><Value /></Type.Property>` It's well formed xml that maps directly to a type, as it is deserialized directly to instances of the type. Learning what xaml is, how it works, would be beneficial and wouldn't take long...

Comment: As you can see Will, the answer was not so obvious. So responding with FFS's and Goddamnit's is very offensive. Yes, the property was obvious to me too but the usage was not, as I demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: HeaderLocation was on the page.  All you had to do was ctrl-f, then search, then click the link.  It wasn't that hard.  As for not understanding how to set a property value in xaml, that's a different issue.  Also, not that hard.  You realize, when you say "I looked here XYZ and did not find the solution" and the solution is right there at that link, it's a wtf moment.  Anyhow, you have your answer, and you know how to set property values in xaml.  And I'll wish a good day to you, sir.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who might be stumped at something not-so-obvious, here is the XAML solution I was looking for. Yes, the property was obviously called HeaderLocation but DevExpress' documentation does not give any XAML examples on this. So here is what I came up with that solved my case:

```
<dx:DXTabControl>
    <dx:DXTabControl.View>
        <dx:TabControlMultiLineView HeaderLocation="Bottom"/>
    </dx:DXTabControl.View>
    <dx:DXTabItem Header="Main">
        <dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
            <dxdo:LayoutGroup>
                <dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="TaskList">
                    <views:DxTaskList x:Name="Tasklst" />
                </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
                <dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="TaskDetails">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Focusable="False">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <views:TaskDetails x:Name="TaskDtls"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
            </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
        </dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
    </dx:DXTabItem>
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

As you can see you're supposed to add the View property and then assign it a value, which I used a TabControlMultiLineView, and that object had a HeaderLocation property to which I set it to one of the valid enums. When I did this, the tabs appeared at the bottom.